# HAProxy Ingress Controller on GKE

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, haproxy, kubernetes-ingress

Is HAProxy Ingress Controller fit to use on GKE?

I installed it, but can't find any information about how to make GKE to use it instead of GKE Ingress Controller. For example, with Nginx IC, you pass the annotation to Ingress resource, as follows:

```
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
```

Is there an equivalent for HAProxy? Or any other way?

Answer (score 2):

We are using haproxy-ingress in GKE. See instructions [here](https://github.com/jcmoraisjr/haproxy-ingress)

Edit: 
You don't need to specify a specific annotation in under Ingress resource for haproxy-ingress to work. haproxy-ingress provides you with a set of [annotations](https://github.com/jcmoraisjr/haproxy-ingress#annotations) that you can use if you need any of them. for example:

```
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: rewire
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
```

Comment: Thank you. I was expecting to use the official HAProxy repo, but this one works too.